# How to handle errors with exception filter while deploying ASP .NET Core 5 application using Linux Docker containers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker

I have an exception filter in my application - a mechanism used to handle all the exceptions occuring in my system. The definition of such a filter is presented here:

```
public sealed class ExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private const string ResponseContentType = "application/json";

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
    {
        var response = exceptionContext.HttpContext.Response;
        var message = exceptionContext.Exception.Message;
        var statusCode = FindCorrespondingStatusCode(exceptionContext.Exception);
            
        CreateResponseAsync(response, message, statusCode).Wait();
    }
        
    private static async Task CreateResponseAsync(HttpResponse response,
        string errorMessage,
        HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
            new
            {
                Message = errorMessage,
                StatusCode = (int) statusCode,
            });

        response.StatusCode = (int) statusCode;
        response.ContentType = ResponseContentType;
        await response.WriteAsync(result);
    }

    private static HttpStatusCode FindCorrespondingStatusCode(Exception exception) =>
        exception switch
        {
            ArgumentNullException _ => HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
            NullReferenceException _ => HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
            UnauthorizedAccessException _ => HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
            _ => HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
        };
}
```

When any exception occurs in the application i can always rely on prepared response with exception descritpion in message field thanks to ExceptionFilter. This solution works if i use an application with the IIS/IIS Express. My api returns proper messages, for example if user tries to sign up with invalid password, my web api will return the following response:

```
{
  "Message": "Password must be at least 8 characters long, must contain a digit, a capital english letter, lower case english letter, and one special character",
  "StatusCode": 500
}
```

The problem is, when i try to run my application on Docker containers, it uses Kestrel server instead of IIS. And if any exception occurs, api returns only empty response, so the mechanism does'nt work for some reason just because i use Kestrel instead of IIS i guess. I've checked some logs on the container and i've found the following exception:
"
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]

Connection id "0HM8CJ9JFRGLB", Request id "0HM8CJ9JFRGLB:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

User.Domain.User.Exceptions.InvalidPasswordException: Password must be at least 8 characters long, must contain a digit, a capital english letter, lower case english letter, and one special character
"
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `exceptionContext.ExceptionHandled = true;` in your `OnException` event handler.

But the root of the problem is that you are using `ExceptionFilterAttribute` which is legacy and deprecated from MVC days - you should instead either [implement `IExceptionFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-filters) or [call `IApplicationBuilder.UseExceptionHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-handler-lambda) and pass in your exception handler (can easily be a call to another method, doesn't have to be inline as per Microsoft's example). Either of those options would also fix that you are calling async code in a synchronous manner, which is guaranteed to cause you problems somewhere down the line.